# Join lines of text with repeated beginning with numbers

Tags: sed, join

I was wondering if someone can help me out here as I'm trying to apply nothing but "`sed` with regular expression" to an XML file. I feel the approach is similar in nature.

I would like to use the `sed` command with the following file.

```
ABC
12345
54321
98765
56789
DEFG
07418
8529
BBBG
12365
9879
8596
7485
NMKL
3652
4523
12345 192.168.1.12
54321 10.10.2.23
98765 192.168.2.52
56789 172.16.2.2
07418 192.168.11.56
8529 10.11.3.55
9879 10.17.25.12
8596 192.168.7.23
7485
3652 172.28.28.1
4523 172.56.56.7
```

And to convert it into something like

```
ABC
12345 12345 192.168.1.12
54321 54321 10.10.2.23
98765 98765 192.168.2.52
56789 56789 172.16.2.2
DEFG
07418 07418 192.168.11.56
8529 8529 10.11.3.55
BBBG
12365
9879 9879 10.17.25.12
8596 8596 192.168.7.23
7485 4523 172.56.56.7
NMKL
3652 3652 172.28.28.1
4523 4523 172.56.56.7
```

or even better

```
ABC
12345 192.168.1.12
54321 10.10.2.23
98765 192.168.2.52
56789 172.16.2.2
DEFG
07418 192.168.11.56
8529 10.11.3.55
BBBG
12365
9879 10.17.25.12
8596 192.168.7.23
7485 172.56.56.7
NMKL
3652 172.28.28.1
4523 172.56.56.7
```

I'm sure that it is obvious that the numbers in the first column are considered an ID that is linked to an IP address at the bottom of the page.

The id also falls under letter abbreviations. Using the similar command

```
sed -E '$!N;/^(\S+\s+)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2<br>/;D'
```

with few modification, I feel I'm close.

My attempts have failed such as with the following

```
sed -E '$!N;/^([0-9]+)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2 /;D' file.xml
```

or

```
sed -E '$!N;/^([[:digit:]]+)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2 /;D' file.xml
```

The file started off as an XML, and I have slowly removed unnecessary information. The ID number can increase in size. All spaces are single spaces. Basically, I’d like to match the ID number under the abbreviation that corresponds with the IP address, and place that ID an IP address under the abbreviation.

I kind of feel that the capturing group is not pick all lines that begin with numbers. I also feel that the `sed` regular expression might require an if condition, I’m just not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: Using sed to parse an XML file is error-prone, especially if applied to multiple files after. Besides programming, I don't know an CLI alternative to solve your task, but others might. If you insist on using sed, I assume will be easier to break the task into multiple sed commands that each manage a simpler subtask.

Comment: (1) Please never ever place example text as image. If people have an answer, they can't test it with the example file. Edit your answer to copy&paste real text. See the help to find out how to format it (indent by four spaces to format as code). (2) I don't find it obvious, why the `7485` line is appended with the `4523` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, I feel that your example doesn't match your explanation, but I assume you actually look for something like

```
sed 'H;x;s/\(\n[0-9]*\)\(\n.*\)*\1\( .*\)$/\1\3\2/;h;$!d;s/^\n//
```

The idea is to collect all lines in the hold space and test if the last line starts with an ID we already had before:

- `H;x` means we append all lines to the hold space and then exchange hold space and pattern space. Note that this places a useful newline at the beginning
- `s/\(\n[0-9]*\)\(\n.*\)*\1\( .*\)$/\1\3\2/` finds the ID line (consisting of only digits) and tests if last appended line matches that ID. If yes, move the rest of the line behind the ID. The `*` behind `(\n.*)* seems nonsense, but is neccessary to handle the case, when the IP line could be immediately behind the ID line.
- `h;$!d` saves the line back to the hold space and continues with the next line without output
- `s/^\n//` finally removes the starting newline
  ;x;s/(\n[0-9]*)(\n.*)\1([0-9 .]*)/\1\3\2/;x;$!d;g;s/^\n//'

**Update for extended regular expressions**

If you want to use extended regular expressions (option `-E`, as in your question), the syntax would be

```
sed 'H;x;s/(\n[0-9]*)(\n.*)*\1( .*)$/\1\3\2/;h;$!d;s/^\n//
```

but please note that backreferences (`\1`) are not part of the POSIX ERE standard, so it may not be implemented by all `sed` flavours.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Sed’s hold space seem to be out of my wheel house, so I very much appreciate your explaining the process. Currently the command works well on the command line, I just need to integrate it into a sed script. I seem to be getting a back-reference error.  I execute the sed script as sed -E -f sed-script.sed file.xml.  Any thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: With extended regular expressions (`-E`) the backslashes before ( and ) need to be dropped.